# Shortcut to Link OK Button with an underlying ListBox

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
If CommandButton1_Click.Clicked Then
Dim i As Long, j As Long

j = 0
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        j = j + 1
        SummaryEquities.Cells(j, 1).Value = ListBox1.List(i)
    End If
Next i
Else
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

End Sub
```

I want to connect the OK button (CommandButton1_Click()) to the my selection of of Markets and insert the values chosen from the list in cell list A1 - rest. I think I've got the correct code to extract the selected markets, but I am struggling to find a way to connect this to the OK button. There must be a shortcut. Any help?

Comment: Not sure I understand, do you mean your existing code you want to fire on the command click?

Comment: You basically got the answer in your own code. Write your code under the `CommandButton1_Click` event and you'r done (without the `If..` statement ofcourse ;)).

Comment: @JvdV Ok Thanks, and how do I remove the Window(UserForm) after clicking ok... simply using "Exit" in the code does not work unfortunately

Comment: Use `Unload Me`